# Validity of Ticket After Change

Tags: tickets, fares

Let's say I buy an air ticket which allows changes with no fee. The ticket is valid for one year since the date of issue, and if it's partially used, up to one year from the date of the first outbound flight.

What happens to ticket validity in case the change is processed as revalidation? Similarly, will validity be extended in case the change requires reissue?

Comment: This is probably specific to the airline and/or the fare. Check the conditions of carriage and the fare rules (both the original and new ones). I personally wouldn’t be surprised if in a majority of cases validity remained unchanged, though. There could have been a few exceptions these days due to Covid, but the impact on accounts and the balance sheet makes airlines quite hesitant to extend validity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, the Air Canada tariff has a fine print.

Rule 85, D.
The expiration date of any new ticket issued will be the same as the expiration date of the old ticket.